# Test the performance of a grid when loading 600,000 records using JMeter

Tags: jmeter, performance, jmeter-plugins

We have an application where we load data from the database to a grid view so users can view the records.

Usually 100,000 to 600,000 records will be loaded in this grid, with 600,000  as the maximum. While the records are loading, we need to analyze the application's performance.

How we can do this using JMeter?

Also do we need this number of data records in the DB to validate performance using JMeter? Or can we configure JMeter to validate that same data load without having the records in the database?

Answer (score 1):

Testing the performance of web applications is pretty straightforward:

1. Record your application use cases with browser and [HTTP(S) Test Script Recorder](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP(S)_Test_Script_Recorder)
2. Perform [correlation](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-to-handle-correlation-in-jmeter) of the dynamic parameters if needed
3. Perform [parameterization](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#CSV_Data_Set_Config) of your test if needed (i.e. if you want different users to use different credentials).
4. Run your test with 1 user and 1 loop to ensure that it is doing what it supposed to be doing inspecting requests and responses with [View Results Tree](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#View_Results_Tree) listener
5. Run your test with full load
6. [Generate reporting dashboard](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/generating-dashboard.html), analyse results, find bottleneck, rise issues, etc.

Particular in your case you can also add an extra check of displayed data matching the data in the database using i.e. [JDBC PostProcessor](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JDBC_PostProcessor) and [Response Assertion](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Response_Assertion) so your test would fail automatically if there is an inconsistency in the data.

Comment: Thanks for the input  how to configure 600000 data load in the Jmeter

Comment: @dimitri T Thank you for your valuable feedback Would it be possible for you to elabarate following point more in detail  

Particular in your case you can also add an extra check of displayed data matching the data in the database using i.e. JDBC PostProcessor and Response Assertion so your test would fail automatically if there is an inconsistency in the data.

Answer (score 0):

For your Usecase you need to have 600000 real record in your database.

You can try following ways for that :

1. Generate some random record and insert into the database you can ask developer to create some Store procedure to do that.
2. You can use selenium script to generate and insert random data for your application using application UI.

So once you have these testdata ready in your application then go with JMeter and do configure.

- Create one `Thread Group`

  - add one `HTTP Request Sampler` - there you have to provide the URL of the page where you have grid to load those many records.
  - add one `View Results Tree` Listener to view the request and response for debugging purpose

If you require to do some additional in JMeter for your deed then please explore some JMeter tutorial

Comment: @ Narendra Thank you  right now we are generating random records to DB using selenium script. Will keep you posted